# JQuery, unique id

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with two date input fields.

I would like to use DatePicker.
In order to get a calendar pop-up for each field, I would need to use a unique id.

How do I create a unique id but at the same time refer to one(1) "DatePicker" JQuery function?

I have tried:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

with

```
id="1datepicker"
id="2datepicker"
```

and

```
$( "#.datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

with

```
id="1.datepicker"
id="2.datepicker"
```

Below is the code

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#.datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } 
  );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="1datepicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="2datepicker"></p>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="1.datepicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="2.datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate **refer to one(1) "DatePicker" JQuery function**??

Comment: Why can't use a class?

Comment: If you still want to go with `id` I would say keep the `unique_identifier` at the end, something like `datepicker1` and `datepicker2` and then you can use `$('id^="datepicker").datepicker()`

Comment: "In order to get a calendar pop-up for each field, I would need to use a unique id." No, not at all. In general terms, assigning IDs to everything tends to make things more complicate, not easier.

Comment: Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using ids, you could use a class to select your element in Jquery. Each of your datepicker would still have a unique Ids, but jquery would select both.

Also, your ids can't start with a number. [see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".picker" ).datepicker();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="picker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="picker"></p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its best practice to use class when we need to do same activity for group of DOM elements. We can still have Ids for the datepickers when we want to set/get values.

```js
$(document).ready( function() { //This will fire only after DOM is ready
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } 
);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker1"></p>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker2"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker3"></p>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker4"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker5"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a special css class instead of the id. That way all your datepicker input fields can (and must!) have different ids and your script can call them by the class name.

Please have in mind that ids and classes are not allowed to start with a number!